# Java program with 2 native methods declared and defined in C and C++

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

Can anyone give me an example of a Java program which has two native methods declared and defined in C and C++. Actually, I need a procedure as well as the code, so that I can run it and learn from it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with JNI  [Java Native Interface]

[Check this tutorial WIN env](http://cnd.netbeans.org/docs/jni/beginning-jni-win.html)

[**Linux** Environment :-) better one](http://cnd.netbeans.org/docs/jni/beginning-jni-linux.html)

Comment: Now it's working, when I first clicked it, it said that the ressource was not found in the library (or similar)

Comment: @org.life.java  The file /web/projects/platform/docs/jni/beginning-jni-win.html appears to be missing. this is comming after clicking it.

Comment: @org.life.java  pleas Give a link or code if u know any other.

Comment: @ org.life.java  thanks its coming . Can you provide me the same for Linux environment .I want to do it in linux

Comment: @yosanu You are welcomed, and yes you can always upvote it or accept it as answer if this is the case,updated the answer

Comment: @org.life.java thanks this is a nice tutarial ,hope to meet you with another java question .

Comment: @yosanu Sure, you are probably in hurry and forgot to upvote and you forgot to accept it as answer :-)

Comment: @ org.life.java Ok you also upvote my question. and make it favourite .

Comment: @org.life.java What does "org.life.java" mean.

Comment: @yosanu Its just a nick name. a psychology behind this name is my life is an organization and java is a module of it :-)

Comment: @org.life.java are u working on Google App engine .Basically it supports python well. also supports java.

Comment: @org.life.java actually I am currently working on it to develop some facebook apps.